# Mongodb users in replica

Tags: replication, mongodb

1) I have mongo instances A, B and C, each having a different set of users with different roles. I have used mongo shell to connect with A through an Admin user. Now, to create a replica and add B and C, do I need to pass through auth on B and C. Can you please help me with the commands?

2) I have mongo instances A, B and C, each having a different set of users with different roles. After I create a replica with A, B and C, what happens to the users of individual nodes. Are all the users from each node available in the replica?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, currently all the nodes(A, B and C) are running as standalone nodes with a different set of data.

Now you are trying to establish a replica with the existing nodes.

As per your question, first, you are trying to convert node A to a replica set member and then adding B and C to the replica set. So mostly, in this case, node A will become primary and B and C will be added as secondary. Since B and C are added as secondary for one time it will replicate all data from A. This one time process is called [Initial Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync).

When Initial Sync is happening, mongod removes the contents of the dbPath directory of B and C node.

Please follow the steps in [Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#procedure) to set up the replica set.

Answering your second question, this procedure will delete all users and data from Node B and C.

Comment: ,this procedure will delete all users and data from Node B and C. I don't think so it will delete the rest of the users from that which node is participating the secondary replica node in the cluster.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan , please check mongodb initial sync process

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Please check the **WARNING** given in the following link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#automatically-sync-a-member

Comment: From one mongod, can I initiate a replica and add other mongod instances into the replica set without passing through the auth of that other mongod instances?

Comment: You can authenticate members of replica sets and sharded clusters. For the internal authentication of the members, MongoDB can use either **keyfiles** or **x.509 certificates**. Please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#enforce-keyfile-access-control-on-existing-replica-set to enable **keyfile** authentication between replica set members.

Answer (score 0):

> I have mongo instances A, B and C, each having a different set of
>   users with different roles. I have used mongo shell to connect with A
>   through an Admin user. Now, to create a replica and add B and C, do I
>   need to pass through auth on B and C. Can you please help me with the
>   commands?

As **`@AdamC`** has been already stated that [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64614/admin-db-replicated-in-mongodb-replica-set) If they are members of the same replica set, then no. The users will be written to the primary and then replicated to the secondaries - remember any secondary can become primary in a normal set, so you would have to have all the data necessary to do that, including users. If the nodes are in the set when they are added, the users will replicate normally. If you add them later, they will replicate the users as part of the initial sync process.

Suppose that you have 3 node replica set like as A,B,C

The Node A there is configuration file as (**A.conf**)

For example I am mentioning the node A configuration file

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/A
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.xxx.xxx,localhost
  port: 27011                --- node A port no
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/Example-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/A/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: StackExachange-example
```

Node **B.conf** file

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/B
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.xxx.xxx,localhost
  port: 27012                --- node B port no
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/Example-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/B/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: StackExachange-example
```

Node **C.conf** file

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/mongodb/db/C
net:
  bindIp: 192.168.xxx.xxx,localhost
  port: 27013                --- node C port no
security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /var/mongodb/pki/Example-keyfile
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /var/mongodb/db/C/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
processManagement:
  fork: true
replication:
  replSetName: StackExachange-example
```

> Note: Here the dbpath of every node (i.e., A,B,C will be different)

After making the configuration file of A,B,C with thier different path start the mongod server process.

Starting mongod processes with A.conf, B.conf and C.conf:

```
mongod -f A.conf
mongod -f B.conf
mongod -f C.conf
```

after starting the mongod process of all node, suppose that I will connect to node A
with mongo shell

```
mongo --port 27011  --- here port no 27011 is port no of A
```

Initiating the replica set:

```
rs.initiate()
```

Creating a user:

use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "StackExchange-admin",
  pwd: "StackExchange-pass",
  roles: [
    {role: "root", db: "admin"}
  ]
})

> Note : Here I am creating the user and password of admin database of
>   node A.

Exiting out of the Mongo shell and connecting to the entire replica set:

```
exit
mongo --host "StackExchange-example/192.168.xxx.xxx:27011" -u "StackExchange-admin"
-p "StackExchange-pass" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Getting replica set status:

```
rs.status()
```

Adding other members to replica set:

```
rs.add("B:27012")
rs.add("C:27013")
```

Getting an overview of the replica set topology:

```
rs.isMaster()
```

Stepping down the current primary:

```
rs.stepDown()
```

Checking replica set overview after election:

```
rs.isMaster()
```

> I have mongo instances A, B and C, each having a different set of
>   users with different roles. After I create a replica with A, B and C,
>   what happens to the users of individual nodes. Are all the users from
>   each node available in the replica?

Here as I understood the mongo instances (A,B,C) means that three mongod. Suppose that among three of node A,B,C they have some different users with different roles . Suppose that when replication has been made with the node A as primary replica set with their admin database & their roles authentication.

As whatever before the replication you have the Users & roles of the the node B,C it will be remain there but after the replication if you shall create new users or roles to members of replica then need to [Resync a Member of a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/)

For further your ref [here](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-users-roles-explained-part-2/) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync) and [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/setup-mongodb-replica-set/)

Comment: From one mongod, can I initiate a replica and add other mongod instances into the replica set without passing through the auth of that other mongod instances?

Comment: @Raman, Yes, you can. But the three node replica folder will be different to each other.